# При нажатии на вложенный html элемент срабатывает и его функция и функция того элемента, в который он вложен

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть два html элемента, `элемент 2`  вложен в `элемент 1` , в оба элемента встроено по отдельной функции при нажатии `Onclick=""`. При нажатии на `элемент 2` и его функция и функция `элемента 1`, а мне это не надо. Как можно `элемент 2` ограничить, чтоб при нажатии только его функция срабатывала?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто не вкладывай один в другой и через позиционирование поставь их так как тебе нужно. Приложи код к вопросу, будут ответы подробнее

Comment: Нужно вызывать функцию StopPropagation()

Comment: Вот что про такое пишут в учебниках - https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling

Answer (score 0):

в `элемент 2` добавить `event.stopPropagation()`, чтоб он выглядел следующим образом:
`onclick="someFunct();event.stopPropagation()"`. Спасибо людям из комментариев за помощь